# I'm trying to use native C++ libraries in a MAUI app and cannot get it working for MacOS/iOS

Tags: c++, ios, static, native, maui

There's a great article here that describes how to use native C++ libraries in Xamarin/C#, and I would assume that this would extend to MAUI:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/cpp/

I followed these instructions, and put together an end-to-end demo solution of it here:  https://github.com/whodges/bindingsample.  This does require that you link Visual Studio to a MacBook to build the full solution.

That example essentially uses the default MAUI template, and modifies it slightly so that the actual 'click counter' value is set and retrieved from a native library on a per-platform basis.  For Windows, that's a C++ DLL (works great).  For Android, that's a .so library (works great).  And for iOS, that's a static .a library, and here's where I'm running into trouble:  when I try to launch this app using the iOS Simulator, it fails with a clang++ error, and something along the lines of "Could not extract the native library 'libCounteriOS.a' from .../obj/Debug/net6.0-ios/iossimulator-x64/linker-cache/libCounteriOS.a'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary')".

I created a C# .NET iOS Binding Library project (Counter.iOS in my example), and this is supposed to bundle libCounteriOS.a, which is generated when CounteriOS (a C++ project) is compiled.  First, when Counter.iOS is built using Visual Studio on Windows, it fails to generate the Counter.resources folder in its 'bin' folder, along with the subsequent 'manifest' file.  When I use Visual Studio for Mac, these files *do* get generated.  So, I stuck with Visual Studio for Mac to build the iOS.Counter project (everything else is built with Visual Studio on Windows).

Regardless, I still get the "could not extract the native library" error I described.  I've tried setting the library file's Build Action in Counter.iOS to ObjcBindingNativeLibrary, but that just results in an unhelpful "Build failed - see build log for details" error in Visual Studio for Mac, and I cannot find said log file for the life of me.  On top of that, it's not an Objective C library anyway - it's a C++ one - so I'm not sure if this step is actually appropriate.  Does it have to be Objective C?  The Xamarin article suggests otherwise, and the native reference option 'Is C++' is there as well.  I've also tried setting libCounteriOS.a's Build Action to 'BundleResource' - no luck with that either.  I've tried it with .NET 7.0 as well - also no luck there.

I'm really at a loss.  Is this even possible?  It doesn't seem to work and I've been poking at it for weeks on it.  That Xamarin article seems to suggest it should be possible.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.